# Why is the php code not being executed in login system?

Tags: php, html

I have set up a login system using PHP, HTML & SQLi. It was working but now it is not checking to see if the login credentials are correct. I have an if statement in the header so that when the user is successful the icons change and the user name is displayed. I can't seem to see the error, advice would be much appreciated.

sign_in.php

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Sign in</h1>
  <p class="signup_text">Please sign in to access extra features.  Want to comment? Sign in or Sign up! Please use valid credentials.</p>
  <form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?= $_POST['email'] ?>">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?= $_POST['password'] ?>">
    <input name="login" type="submit" class="submit" value="Sign in">
  </form>
  <br><br><br>
</div>
```

header.php (contains html & php)

```
<div class="menu">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <? if ($_SESSION['user']['first_name']): ?>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>Hello <?= $_SESSION['user']['first_name'] ?></a></li>
                        <? endif ?>
                        <li><a href="/"><i class="icon fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/blog"><i class="icon fa fa-book"></i>Blog</a></li>
                        <? if ($_SESSION['user']['first_name']): ?>
                            <li><a href="?action=logout"><i class="icon fa fa-sign-in"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        <? else: ?>
                            <li><a href="/sign_in"><i class="icon fa fa-sign-in"></i>Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/register"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i>Register</a></li>
                            <? endif ?>
                    </ul>               
                </div>
```

mycontrollerclass.php (php function for sign in)

```
 function sign_in() {
            if ($_POST['login']) {
                $db = db();
                $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` ='" . $_POST['email'] . "'")
                if ($result->num_rows > 0)  
                    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
                }
                if ($data['password'] == $_POST['password']) {
                    $this->alerts['success'][] = '<b>Success</b> You have successfully signed in.';
                } else {
                    $this->alerts['error'][] = '<b>Error:</b> Incorrect email or password!';
                }
                if ($result) {
                    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
                        $_SESSION['user'][$k] = $v;
                    } 
                } else {
                    $this->alerts['error'][] = '<b>Error:</b> Login unsuccessful please try again.';
                }
                $db->close();
            }
        }
```

Table in database:

Database name: fw_blog------
Table Name: users-------
Columns: id, first_name, last_name, url, email, password.

Comment: The sign_in function is never been called. And please consult your search engine about "sql injection"

Comment: the function is being called when the user presses the login in button. I understand sql injection, just want to get it running first!

Comment: where is the code to call `sign_in();` when the user presses the login button. You didn't post it.

Comment: @ Steven the code above has no error opps! I didnt save the file when I changed the action attribute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I stupidly put action='/welcome' on the sign_in.php.  This needed to be empty. Works perfect now. When posting this question I had not saved the file which is why it wasn't working! the code above is perfect and has no error.